# Adding text to the div, shifts the div

Tags: html, css

I need a little help. I have attached a basic html code. There are 2 rectangles. The main rectangle with id as "maindiv" and another rectangle with id "subdiv". The "subdiv" is in center of the "maindiv". Now, when I add the text to the "subdiv", it shifts down a little and the "subdiv" is not in the center of the "maindiv" anymore. What should I do to:

1. Put the text in center of the "subdiv".
2. Keeping 1 in mind, i get the "subdiv" in center of "maindiv".

[JSFiddle (Without adding text)](https://jsfiddle.net/qoq1j2kv/)

[JSFiddle (After adding text)](https://jsfiddle.net/pobtxpet/)

**Full Code:**

```css
p {
  color: white;
}
#maindiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#subdiv {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 30%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}
.rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="maindiv" class="rectangle">
    <div id="subdiv" class="rectangle">
      <p>Rectangle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here you go [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pobtxpet/4/)

Comment: Thanks :), It helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please apply following style to your subdiv, so your text will be at center position as well as your subdiv also.

```
#subdiv{
position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: brown;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: It helps, Thank you :)

Comment: @SamarjoyPandit, you are welcome. Do accept or up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers add margin for the `p` tag by default, remove that with `margin:0` and it won't happen:

```css
p {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

#maindiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#subdiv {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 30%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="maindiv" class="rectangle">
    <div id="subdiv" class="rectangle">
      <p>
        Rectangle
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p{
                color: white;
            }
            #maindiv{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            #subdiv{
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                top: 30%;
                width: 60%;
                height: 40%;
                background-color: brown;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .rectangle{
                height: 200px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: yellowgreen;
            }
          .rectangle p {margin: 0px;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="maindiv" class="rectangle">
            <div id="subdiv" class="rectangle">
                <p>Rectangle</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add margin: 0px to the paragraph in div.

Comment: thanx bro...that solved my 2nd problem...but how do I get the text in the middle and center of the the "subdiv" ?

Answer (score 0):

use **`display:inline`** for your `<p>` tag,it's works fine

```css
p {
  color: white;
  display:inline;
}
#maindiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#subdiv {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 30%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}
.rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="maindiv" class="rectangle">
    <div id="subdiv" class="rectangle">
      <p>Rectangle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

its just because `<p>` tag takes default margin. to remove it add in css

```
p
{
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: thanx bro :)...but how do i get the text in the center of the "subdiv" ? By center i mean: center and middle..

Comment: add textcenter class to subdiv in bootstrap

Comment: to make vertically center use line-height property

Comment: umm...i dont have to use bootstrap... i only have to use html and css...and  using that i have to align the text in middle vertically... :/

Comment: You will ? Thank you bro :)

Comment: just add this in your css

Comment: p{
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:75px;
}

Comment: Ok thanx !! It helps :)

Comment: plz mark this answer as useful so that it'll help other users too!